# How can i fix white-space between picture and progress bard on large screens using Bootstrap Grid systen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, grid-system

[image]let first show you the idea in this picture: Picture (1) in this picture we see that the progress bars are under the picture in md/lg screens, and the text is on its right.
[image]

and in picture(2) the text gose second and the progress bars gose last in small screen size:
[image]

what i tried to do is this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mon cv - </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--main container-->
        <header>
            <h1>Bentouhami Faisal</h1>
        </header>

        <!-- Menu Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Mon Portfolio</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="formation.html">Formations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="exprience.html">Expérience</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--end Navbar-->

    <!--header container-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-auto">
                    <!-- Picture -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <img src="images/mon_cv_photo.jpg" alt="Photo de Portfolio" class="rounded-circle">    
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <h2 class="intro-text"> 
                            <p><b> Développeur Full Stack</b></h2></p>
                        <p class="intro-text">
                                36 ans <br> tant que développeur Full Stack, je possède une expertise complète dans
                                la
                                conception, le développement et la maintenance d'applications web. <br> Avec une solide
                                formation en informatique de gestion et une passion pour la programmation, je suis
                                capable
                                de
                                gérer tous les aspects d'un projet, tant sur le plan front-end que back-end.

                                Grâce à ma maîtrise des langages de programmation tels que HTML, CSS, JavaScript, ainsi
                                que des frameworks populaires tels que React et Angular, je peux créer des interfaces
                                utilisateur attrayantes et réactives.<br>

                                En tant que Full Stack développeur, je suis également à l'aise avec les technologies de
                                développement back-end telles que Node.js et Python, ce qui me permet de créer des API
                                performantes et de mettre en place des architectures logicielles robustes. <br>Je suis
                                également
                                familier avec les concepts de déploiement et d'hébergement, et je peux travailler avec
                                des
                                outils tels que Docker et AWS pour assurer une mise en production fluide et sécurisée.

                                <br>En résumé, en tant que développeur Full Stack, je suis en mesure de concevoir,
                                développer et
                                optimiser des applications web complètes, offrant une expérience utilisateur
                                exceptionnelle
                                et
                                des fonctionnalités performantes. Je suis passionné par mon métier et je m'efforce
                                constamment
                                de rester à jour avec les dernières tendances et les meilleures pratiques du
                                développement
                                web.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                 </div>      
                    <!-- Progression bars -->
                    <div class="row">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/java.png" alt="Java" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%;" aria-valuenow="80"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">80%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compétence : C# -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/c-sharp.png" alt="C#" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 70%;" aria-valuenow="70"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">70%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compétence : HTML -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/html-5.png" alt="HTML" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%;" aria-valuenow="90"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">90%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compétence : CSS -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/css-3.png" alt="CSS" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 85%;" aria-valuenow="85"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">85%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compétence : Bootstrap -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/bootstrap.png" alt="Bootstrap" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%;" aria-valuenow="75"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">75%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Compétence : Php -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <img src="images/php.png" alt="Php" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%;" aria-valuenow="70"
                                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">75%</div>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <!--end 1st container-->
</body>
</html>
```

put in red where the progress bars should be.

the problem is when i'm in large screen, the text is too big which puches the progressionn row way under creating a blanc white between the picture and the progression bars !
take a look at this screens:

Comment: Usually you'd use `.input-group` for this, but I don't know if it would work on progress bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this *"using Bootstrap's grid system"* (which, in reality, is not exactly a grid system, but a flex one) is to place the progress bars twice in code (once after the picture and once after the text) and show/hide them using display utility classes ([v4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements), [v5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)).

The one under the picture should have `.d-none.d-md-block` and the one under the text should have `.d-block.d-md-none`.
Change `md` to `sm` or `lg` if you want them to swap at a different breakpoint.
And swap `*-block` for `*-flex` classes if the default display of the element you apply this to is "flex".

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/uky1c8aw/).

Alternatively, you could duplicate the text (instead of the progress bars) and apply the same technique.

---

**Notes:**

- the main disadvantage of this technique is it over-complicates applying/removing event listeners to the duplicated element or its descendants.
  However, some frontend frameworks (Vue, React) offer built-in "portal" components which, in essence, are capable of rendering their contents inside a target element, placed at a different location in DOM, based on controller logic, without losing events (the elements are not destroyed, but moved). To my knowledge, Angular does not offer this out of the box. There might be a plugin for it, though.
- this layout is also possible using bespoke CSS, if the three elements are all children of the same parent, using `display: grid` on the parent and defining `grid-template-areas` (or `grid-template-rows` & `grid-template-columns`) responsively. But this would mean giving up on Bootstrap's grid system for this container and having to write your own CSS for controlling the column widths responsively.
- it's not clear from the sketches you've made if you want the text to be scrollable on mobile while the picture is fixed-top and the progress bars are fixed-bottom. That would undoubtedly create questionable UX. A better user experience on mobile devices is to have the entire page scrollable.
- your markup (HTML) is invalid: you're closing the `<h2>` for title too soon and you're also not closing all layout `<div>`s properly. In principle, your IDE should highlight these for you. Most likely, if you submitted this code for an interview/job application you'd be disqualified right off the bat for not using an IDE (or not knowing how to set it up - for an employer, they mean the same thing).
- other markup issues: do not use `<p>` inside `<h*>` elements (or vice-versa); do not place multiple paragraphs in the same `<p>` element and avoid using `<br>` tags; never place a `.row` as an immediate child of another `.row` (you're supposed to wrap it in a `.col`). And make sure you code passes HMTL validation.

---

I've fixed everything mentioned above in the provided example.

Comment: thank you so much, it works like magic, i need to understand what you have changed, thank you so much :)